# Azure Functions Multiple Actions On Single Functions

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I am developing an API using Azure Functions. Should I have a small number of functions and call many diffrent actions E.G
my Url parameters might contain

```
?action=method1
```

or

```
?action=method2
```

and then perhaps use a switch statement like this:

```
            var action = query["action"].ToString();
            switch (action)
            {
                case "method1":
                    return await method1();
                case "method2":
                    return await method2();
                ....
```

This way I only really need one function to accomplish many actions. Is this a wise way forward? Should I intead have one function for each method? I am confused.

Comment: From personal experience I like individual functions that are isolated in responsibility. If method1 and method2 do similar things then maybe keeping them together makes sense. Personally I would probably split them up but you don't really provide much info to go on. There's also durable functions and entity functions to consider. They could perhaps fit better but without knowing what you are doing it's hard to say either way

Comment: Just typical CRUD stuff really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly It depends on the logic you want, if you use the switch you could use only one function URL to do the request(only need pass the query parameter).

If you use multiple functions, the URL will be chang(firstly the function name, then is the authorization key).

And if all methods are totally different, if you split them to multiple functions, this could reduce some running time like judgment even it won't take much time.

Hope this could help you if you still have other problems please provide more details.

Comment: I was just worried that there would be a compelling reason NOT to you use the switch way. It seems that I could have a Function for GET and a function for POST.

Comment: If you could write all logics right, I suppose the function could work.

Comment: @Paul Stanley, if this could help you, you could accept it as the answer.